# Trigger "second" document ready from a partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have SiteA and SiteB.

I am trying to load a partial view from SiteB into a dialog in SiteA .

Like this:

```
//This is done SiteA 
$("#selector").load("SiteB/View");
```

doc ready of SiteB/View:

```
//This is done SiteB 
 $(document).ready(function () {

    home.redirectUrl = 'www.url.com';
    home.initializePage('data');
    home.initializeEvents();

});
```

Home is initialized on a script referenced above that code. But it seems that it will try the code inside the document ready before the referenced script loads properly so I get that home is 'undefined'. So it does not behave as a "second" document ready.

So i need to find a way to actually make it behave as such or is it another way around this problem ?

Also if I access SiteB/View by it's self on the browser it works fine.

Comment: ajax calls would be the same to achieve this asynchronous loading

Comment: You can try to move the script in siteA and use the .done callback of the ajax method